# PHP - How to 'parse data' from database using one method

Tags: php

I have tried a few different ways to make this work to no avail.

Basically, I have these 4 lines that are in many functions:

```
function getID($URL){
  //These 3 plus this comment line
    $parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where URL=\"$URL\"";
    $parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ); // Run the Query
    $link = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult); // Query Result
...continues...
```

That basically tells the database to check $URL and if it matches the URL string in the database, it grabs all of the data associated with that URL, and I grab what I need with

```
$link['ID'];
```

Which would give me the ID associated with the $URL URL.

The function checks a list of conditionals that either print the 'override' variable ($ID), the default variable ($defaultID) or pulls from the server ($link['ID']), like below. The 'override' is a variable outside of the function that is currently called in by global $ID.

```
$ID = ''; //Overrides if set
function parseData($URL){
  //Initialize Query for Table Data
    $parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where URL=\"$URL\"";
    $parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ); // Run the Query
      return mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult); // Query Result  
};
function getID($URL){
  global $ID;
  $serverID = parseData($URL);
    if(empty($ID)){
      if(empty($serverID)){
        echo $defaultID; 
      } else { echo $serverID['ID']; }
    }//end of ifs
    else 
      { echo $ID; } 
};
```

Comment: nothing to do with the answer, but why not `$parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where URL='$URL'";`? Also, if you're not aware, Mysql_* is deprecated. Use Mysqli or PDO

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know it is depreciated but it's how the site is built for now. That line was made by a previous developer, it worked so I didn't touch it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Your penultimate paragraph (_The function checks a list of conditionals_...) is a bit confusing (remove it if it's not relevant to the question). It seems to me that if you have "4 lines that are in many functions" then you should add those to a separate function so the code is written just once - is that what you mean in you last para? If so, and "nothing has worked so far", can you outline what you did try, so we can see what might be wrong with it?

Comment: Please check what you have in your `$URL` variable and what is in the db; perhaps in db you don't have `http://` or you have `http:// example.com/` while `$URL` equals to `http:// example.com/` (with last /).

Comment: $URL is just the path that follows .com/ - that's how it is in the database and actual file system.

Comment: Your `getID` function has two sets of braces - is that really what you have in your code?

Comment: Force of habit. Just imagine the inner braces contain a lot more code. I sometimes wrap where it isn't technically needed to make my code more organize. Were that all the function did I wouldn't have put them, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you you want to parse the data row you would need search criteria `$criterion` and a field you you want it to return:

```
function getField($criterion, $returnField){
    $parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where URL='".$criterion."' LIMIT 1"; // also make sure you  that $criterion is safe to use in a query
    $parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ); // Run the Query
    if ($parentResult)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult);
        return $row[$returnField];
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it:

`$linkId = getField($url, 'ID');`

Comment: Just edited. Missed a DOT `'".$criterion"'` should be `'".$criterion."'`

Comment: Worked great, just had to change $result to $parentResult. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're just trying to refactor that function so you don't have to keep on re-writing it. Is that correct?

If so, you can extract a new function like this:

```
function getLink($URL){
    $parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where URL=\"$URL\"";
    $parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ); // Run the Query
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
function getID($URL){
    $link = getLink($URL);
}
```

Comment: you should not play with raw parameters in query statement

Comment: That's copied directly from the original post.

Comment: Hmm.. still isn't working. Just prints default since no override exists and no server declared ID is available. That is what I'm wanting though, yes. I'll update the original post.